# Flutter: OTP not sent to phone

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am trying to send OTP to verify phone number. I am able to login using the phone number and OTP saved for testing while enabling the phone verification in Firebase. It shows one user logged in with date but no OTP is sent to the phone. It allows me to log in to the 'homePage' using the my original number and the OTP saved in for testing purpose. If I try another number it takes me to the OTP input screen.This is the console status on loging in using the saved OTP. What should I do to get OTP on phone? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Console messages:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 6 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60202/Zelgxfau2Vo=/ws
Syncing files to device Redmi 6 Pro...
D/FirebaseAuth( 7547): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 7547): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 7547): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
I/DpmTcmClient( 7547): RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
W/System  ( 7547): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7547): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 7547): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
W/System  ( 7547): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 7547): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 7547): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Iui0hIPD5YQuNykWTMVBcdjIzyE3 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 7547): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( Iui0hIPD5YQuNykWTMVBcdjIzyE3 ).
W/FirebaseAuth( 7547): [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
```

Here is my code:

```
// Main.dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:phone_verification/screens/homeScreen.dart';

enum MobileVerificationState {
  SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE,
  SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE,
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  MobileVerificationState currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE;

  final phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final otpController = TextEditingController();

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 late String verificationId;

 bool showLoading = false;

  void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {

    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      final authCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      if(authCredential.user != null)
        {
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));
        }

    }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.message.toString())));
    }
  }

  getMobileFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: phoneController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Phone Number"),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: ()async {

            setState(() {
              showLoading = true;
            });

            await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: phoneController.text,
              verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
              },
              verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(verificationFailed.message.toString())));
              },
              codeSent: (verificationId, resendingToken) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                  currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE;
                  this.verificationId = verificationId;
                });
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) async {

              },
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "SEND",
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  getOtpFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: otpController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter OTP"),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
            PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

          },
          child: Text(
            "VERIFY",
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
          child: showLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : currentState == MobileVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE
              ? getMobileFormWidget(context)
              : getOtpFormWidget(context),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),

      ));
  }
}
```

---

```
// loginPage.dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:phone_verification/screens/homeScreen.dart';

enum MobileVerificationState {
  SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE,
  SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE,
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  MobileVerificationState currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE;

  final phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final otpController = TextEditingController();

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 late String verificationId;

 bool showLoading = false;

  void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {

    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      final authCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      if(authCredential.user != null)
        {
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));
        }

    }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {

      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.message.toString())));
    }
  }

  getMobileFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: phoneController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Phone Number"),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: ()async {

            setState(() {
              showLoading = true;
            });

            await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: phoneController.text,
              verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
              },
              verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                });
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(verificationFailed.message.toString())));
              },
              codeSent: (verificationId, resendingToken) async {
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = false;
                  currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE;
                  this.verificationId = verificationId;
                });
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) async {

              },
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "SEND",
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  getOtpFormWidget(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        TextField(
          controller: otpController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter OTP"),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
            PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: otpController.text);

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

          },
          child: Text(
            "VERIFY",
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
          child: showLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : currentState == MobileVerificationState.SHOW_MOBILE_FORM_STATE
              ? getMobileFormWidget(context)
              : getOtpFormWidget(context),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),

      ));
  }
}
```

---

```
// homeScreen.dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phone_verification/screens/loginScreen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _auth.signOut();
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.logout),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with the same piece of code.Any Solution ??@Tom

Comment: Can somebody help please , i'm a litttle stuck here

Comment: hi @J.Koriya, did you find a solution for this, I've been stuck with that problem for more than a week... it was working just fine and suddenly it stopped working I don't know why!!